# ModalWindow does not work properly in Opera

Tags: java, wicket, opera

The ModalWindow does not work properly in Opera. Window content is not displayed but the browser's error page is displayed The browser says "Internal communication error: Check that the address is spelled correctly, or try searching for the site." an a text "http:///" is in the search bar of the error page.

Is there any solution available? I am using wicket 1.3.6.

Thanks and regards.

Edit: This is a screenshot from wicket example of the modal window error in opera 11. "Show modal dialog with a page" gave this error, but for "Show modal dialog with a panel" it's working:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Post some code.  Wicket modal windows have no problem with Opera, so this isn't a general problem, and has something to do with your implementation.

Comment: "I am using wicket 1.3.6."  No, as far as Opera is concerned, you're using HTML (or something similar).  Figure how to get it to work in the HTML (which has nothing to do with Java, or Wicket), then translate that back to Wicket.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket13/ajax/modal-window) and see it work in Opera.  After that, look at the source code for the example and discover where you're doing something different.

**Update:**

It appears there really is an issue in doing the "modal window with a page" in Opera, as I've now seen the same thing.  I wasn't on a machine with Opera yesterday but this morning I tried the example cited above and clicking on "Show modal dialog with a page" does indeed give the issue.

Using Wicket Ajax Debug, I'm seeing a message "INFO: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable" after receiving the Ajax response.

Searching the web for this message suggests it is tied in with the Opera security model dealing with cross-frame scripting.  I see nothing specifically about Wicket, but there may be hints there.

The "Show modal dialog with panel" doesn't have this problem, so looking at that source may lead to a reasonable workaround.

I can't spend much time on it immediately, but I'll continue looking, and let you know if I see the cause.

**Another Update**

This appears to be a known issue in Wicket 1.4, with a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3615).  As we see in this discussion, it actually appeared earlier, but it may only be fixed in 1.5.  The bug report may indicate a way to patch though.

Comment: @Don Roby I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @Tapas Bose:  Note that 'source code' is not a screenshot, but is *immensely* more helpful at debugging the HTML.  I doubt anyone replying to this thread so far, gained a single iota of extra understanding of the problem, by seeing the screenshot.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I said before that modal window with a panel is not throwing that error but with a page is. I am getting maximum help to learn wicket from wicket example, so I am following the technique for modal window as described there. The screenshot is not added to clarify any 'source code' related problem as screenshot is not 'source code'.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson:  Note that the screenshot is of the online example I suggested he look at.  This means that the entire issue is likely in Opera and not in Wicket, and the source won't help.

Comment: @Don Roby thank you. I saw the bug report pointed by you. Are you suggesting to use this patch (due to my lack of knowledge I don't know how to use it, but I will try) or use panel instead of webpage? I will look forward.

Comment: @Tapas - I'd be a bit more inclined to just use a panel, which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the ModalWindow working in Opera, and even under Wicket 1.2

The one reason I can think of your error, is that somehow the webserver is shut down / network unavaible after creation of the link that fires up the ModalWindow. Then, in your browser, you would get an errer like yours.

I had some troubles under Opera 9, where parts of the page would not redraw after closing the dialog, but these seem to have vanished in the newer versions.

Comment: thanks. At least someone replied. But unfortunately there is no such network problem.